# Customize wording of key on iOS keyboard using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, keyboard

I've created a login screen and am wondering if there's a way to customize the wording of the [return] key? Is it possible to change the [return] key's default wording from "return" to the word "Login"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also open up the layout designer and choose the `UITextField` or `UISearchBar` and in `Properties -> Widget` there is a property called `Return Key`. You can then choose from certain text from the enum that SushiHangover provided.

Comment: So, the ability to change the wording of the key to something custom (besides the pre-sets) doesn't exist?

Comment: I can't find anything on customizing it... It seems that the wording is bound to what the enumeration defines, and since enums are sealed, you can't change any of the values, or inherit them in a custom enumeration... Also, there doesn't seem to be a string property on the `UITextField` for changing the `ReturnKey`. So making a custom `UITextField` won't solve this either.

Answer (score 2):

`UITextField` has a `ReturnKeyType` property that can set to one of the `UIReturnKeyType` values:

```
public enum UIReturnKeyType : long
{
    Default,
    Go,
    Google,
    Join,
    Next,
    Route,
    Search,
    Send,
    Yahoo,
    Done,
    EmergencyCall,
    Continue
}
```

The "Return" label is from `UIReturnKeyType.Default`, there is no 
"Login", but maybe one of the others will work.

Re: [Apple Docs: iOS UIReturnKeyType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireturnkeytype)